# How to make an array of objects out of two non symmetrical arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

am stuck now for the whole day and cannot get any further. I know, that I am missing a small thing, but just can't find it.

I got two arrays:

```
arrKeys = ["a", "b", "c"]
arrValues = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I would like to get an array of objects, that looks like:

```
myObj = [
 {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3
 },
 {
  "a": 4,
  "b": 5,
  "c": 6
 },
 {
  "a": 7,
  "b": 8,
  "c": 9
 }
]
```

I tried to do something like:

```
const myObj = arrKeys.reduce((newObj, key, index) => {
  if (arrValues[index] == undefined) arrValues[index] = null
  newObj[key] = aarValues[index]
  return newObj
}, {})
cosnole.log(myObj)
```

But the problem is, that `arrKeys` is looping only once and I do not know, how to "reset" the counter each time `arrKeys` gets to max length. Also I got only an object back, not an array of objects:

My result

```
myObj = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3
 }
```

Any ideas are really appreaciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use modulo operator to get check for every `keys.length` nth element and then add a new object by slicing the values array where the start is current index and end current index + keys.length

```js
const f = (keys, values) => values.reduce((r, e, i) => {
  if (i % keys.length === 0) {
    const index = i / keys.length
    r[index] = values.slice(i, i + keys.length).reduce((r, e, i) => {
      r[keys[i]] = e
      return r
    }, {})
  }

  return r
}, [])

console.log(f(["a", "b", "c"], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
console.log(f(["a", "b", "c", 'g'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
console.log(f(["a", "b"], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the values, creating `arrKeys.length` chunks at a time, and then creating an object from the chunk by mapping the chunk index to the appropriate key. This approach has the advantage that if `arrValues` is not an exact multiple of `arrKeys` length, it will still work:

```js
const f = (arrKeys, arrValues) => {
  const result = []
  const kLen = arrKeys.length
  const vLen = arrValues.length
  for (i = 0; i < vLen; i += kLen) {
    chunk = arrValues.slice(i, i + kLen)
    result.push(Object.fromEntries(chunk.map((v, i) => [arrKeys[i], v])))
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(f(["a", "b", "c"], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
console.log(f(["a", "b", "c"], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]))
console.log(f(["a", "b", "c", "d"], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]))
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to loop through the `arrValues` using a conventional `for...loop`.

We can use the modulus operator `%` to determine where we are in the run of three.

Check the below for a demo:

```js
var arrKeys = ["a", "b", "c"];
var arrValues = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

var myObj = [];
var newObj = null;
for(var i=0; i<arrValues.length; i++)
{
  if(i % 3 === 0) // First run of three
    newObj = {};

  newObj[ arrKeys[i % 3] ] = arrValues[i];
  
  if(i % 3 === 2) // We're at the end of the run of three
    myObj.push(newObj);
}
console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

i do this with `reduce`

```js
const arrKeys = ["a", "b", "c"]
const arrValues = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
let myObj = [];

arrValues.reduce((pre, cur,i) => {
    pre[arrKeys[i % 3]] = cur;
    if (i % 3 === 2) {
        myObj.push(pre);
        return {};
    } else return pre;
}, {})

console.log(myObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do that...

```js
const
  arrKeys   = ['a', 'b', 'c']
, arrValues = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
, myObj = arrValues.reduce((r,v,i) => 
  {
  if (!(i%3)) r.a.push(r.o = {})  
  r.o[arrKeys[i%3]] = v
  return r
  },{ o:null,a:[] }).a
  ; 
console.log(myObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your desire to use `Array#reduce` was a good one, only I would use it:

- To break the larger array into chunks of 3, then
- To convert the chunks into objects

```js
const arrKeys = ["a", "b", "c"],
      arrValues = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
      
      output = arrValues
      .reduce(
          (prev,cur,i,arr) => 
          i % 3 === 0 ? 
              [
                  ...prev, 
                  arr.slice(i, i+3)
                  .reduce(
                      (ac,cu,j) => 
                      ({...ac,[arrKeys[j]]:cu}), {}
                  )
              ] :
              prev, []
      );
      
      
console.log( output );
```